# SQL query to get customer ids not enrolled in products

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have two tables one is products having product id and the other table is customers with information about customers enrolled in some products. Now I want to write a query that returns me ids of the customer and the product they are not enrolled in.

```
Products
Prd
p1
p2  
p3
p4
p5
p6  
    
Cust
CustId Prd
1 p1
1 p2    
1 p4
2 p2
2 p3
3 p1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
select c.custid, p.prd from
(SELECT DISTINCT custid from cust) c
cross join products p
where not exists (select 1 from cust cc where cc.prd = p.prd and cc.custid = c.custid)
```